# XSLT: count tei:lb and print them

Tags: xslt, tei

I have some TEI-files with a rather diverse structure. A rather complete example of special cases is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://www.tei-c.org/release/xml/tei/custom/schema/relaxng/tei_all.rng" type="application/xml"
    schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
      <fileDesc>
         <titleStmt>
            <title>Title</title>
         </titleStmt>
         <publicationStmt>
            <p>Publication Information</p>
         </publicationStmt>
         <sourceDesc>
            <p>Information about the source</p>
         </sourceDesc>
      </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
      <body>
         <div type="section" n="13">
            <p><lb/>[Art. 13]
               <orig>¶ </orig><choice><orig>Jn</orig><reg>In</reg></choice> <choice><orig>ſoͤlcher</orig><reg>sölcher</reg></choice> fürgezogener <choice><orig>Berathſchlagung</orig><reg>Berathschlagung</reg></choice> des
               <lb/>Friedens<orig> /</orig> haben <choice><orig>ſich</orig><reg>sich</reg></choice> gleich als bald auß der erfarnuß<orig> /</orig>
               <lb/><choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> dem jenigen<supplied>,</supplied> <choice><orig>ſo</orig><reg>so</reg></choice> <choice><orig>hieuor</orig><reg>hievor</reg></choice> fürgangen<choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> der <choice><orig>Chůrfürſten</orig><reg>Churfürsten</reg></choice>
               <lb/>Rehte<choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <choice><orig>erſcheynende</orig><reg>erscheynende</reg></choice> <choice><orig>Fürſten</orig><reg>Fürsten</reg></choice><choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> Stendt<choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <choice><orig>Bottſchafften</orig><reg>Bottschafften</reg></choice>
               <lb/><choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> <choice><orig>Geſandten</orig><reg>Gesandten</reg></choice> erinnert<choice><orig>.</orig><reg>:</reg></choice> Dieweyl auff allen
               <lb/>von <choice><orig>Dreyſſig</orig><reg>Dreyssig</reg></choice> oder mehr Jaren<note type="crit_app"><rs type="bibl" ref="#drta_jr_20_4">DRTA.JR 20,4, S. 3107, Z. 29</rs>: <hi rend="italic">danach folgend</hi> der.</note> gehaltenen <choice><orig><w>Reychß
                  <lb rend="trennstrich"/>taͤgen</w></orig><reg><w>Reychß<lb rend="trennstrich"/>tägen</w></reg></choice> <choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> etlichen mehr Particular <choice><orig>verſamblungen</orig><reg>versamblungen</reg></choice><note type="annotation">Teilversammlungen der Reichsstände (u.a. Kurfürstentage).</note><orig> /</orig>
               <lb/>von einem gemeinen<supplied>,</supplied> beharlichen <choice><orig>vnnd</orig><reg>unnd</reg></choice> <choice><orig>beſtendigen</orig><reg>bestendigen</reg></choice>
               <lb/>Frieden<choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <choice><orig>zwiſchen</orig><reg>zwischen</reg></choice> des <rs type="place" ref="#heiliges_roemisches_reich">Heyligen Reychs</rs> Stenden<orig> /</orig>
               <lb/>der <choice><orig>ſtrittigen</orig><reg>strittigen</reg></choice> Religion halben<orig> /</orig> <choice><orig>auffzůrichten</orig><reg>auffzurichten</reg></choice><choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <w>viel
                  <lb rend="trennstrich"/>faltig</w> gehandlet<choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <choice><orig>gerathſchlagt</orig><reg>gerathschlagt</reg></choice><orig> /</orig> <choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> etlich mal <choice><orig><w>Fried
                     <lb rend="trennstrich"/>ſtende</w></orig><reg><w>Fried<lb rend="trennstrich"/>stende</w></reg></choice><note type="annotation">Frieden.</note> auffgericht <choice><orig>woꝛden</orig><reg>worden</reg></choice><choice><orig>.</orig><reg>,</reg></choice><note type="annotation">Vor dem Augsburger Religionsfrieden wurden mit dem <ref type="quelle" target="nuernberger_anstand.xml">Nürnberger Anstand und Kaiserlichen Mandat (1532)<ref type="print">, oben S. #</ref></ref>, dem <ref type="quelle" target="frankfurter_anstand.xml">Frankfurter Anstand (1539)<ref type="print">, oben S. #</ref></ref>, Speyrer Reichsabschied (1544) und <ref type="quelle" target="passauer_vertrag.xml">Passauer Vertrag (1552)<ref type="print">, oben S. #</ref></ref> bereits Regelungen im <rs type="place" ref="#heiliges_roemisches_reich">Reich</rs> zu einzelnen strittigen Fragen in der Religion erreicht (vgl. <rs type="bibl" ref="#kohnle_nuernberg"><surname type="author">Kohnle</surname>, Nürnberg, S. 5-15</rs>).</note> Welche aber <choice><orig>zůerhaltung</orig><reg>zuerhaltung</reg></choice>
               <lb/>des Friedens niemals <choice><orig>genugſam</orig><reg>genugsam</reg></choice> <choice><orig>geweſen</orig><reg>gewesen</reg></choice><choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> <choice><orig>ſonder</orig><reg>sonder</reg></choice><supplied>,</supplied>
               <lb/>deren<orig> /</orig> <choice><orig>vnangeſehen</orig><reg>unangesehen</reg></choice><supplied>,</supplied> die Stende des <rs type="place" ref="#heiliges_roemisches_reich">Reychs</rs><orig> /</orig> für <choice><orig>vnnd</orig><reg>unnd</reg></choice> 
               <lb/>für<note type="annotation">immerzu.</note> in widerwillen <choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> <choice><orig>mißuertrawen</orig><reg>mißvertrauen</reg></choice> gegen einander
               <lb/><choice><orig>ſtehen</orig><reg>stehen</reg></choice> blieben<note type="crit_app"><rs type="bibl" ref="#drta_jr_20_4">DRTA.JR 20,4, S. 3107, Z. 35</rs>: beleiben.</note><choice><orig> /</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> darauß nicht geringer <choice><orig>vnrath</orig><reg>unrath</reg></choice><orig> /</orig> <choice><orig>ſein</orig><reg>sein</reg></choice><note type="crit_app">Fehlt <rs type="bibl" ref="#drta_jr_20_4">DRTA.JR 20,4, S. 3107, Z. 35</rs>.</note> <choice><orig><w>vr
                  <lb rend="trennstrich"/>ſprung</w></orig><reg><w>ur<lb rend="trennstrich"/>sprung</w></reg></choice> erlanget<choice><orig>.</orig><reg>,</reg></choice> Wo <choice><orig>ferꝛ</orig><reg>ferr</reg></choice><note type="annotation">falls.</note> dann inn werender <w>Spal
                     <lb rend="trennstrich"/>tung</w> der Religion ein ergentzte Tractation <choice><orig>vnd</orig><reg>und</reg></choice> <w>hand </w></p></div>
      </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

and I want the `<lb/>`tags to be counted and displayed inside a html-`<span>`at the beginning of every n-th line.

Our `<lb>`-transformations so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3" xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-syntax-grammar-20040210/" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="tei mets xlink exist rdf mods" version="1.0">


      <xsl:template match="tei:lb">
            <xsl:variable name="myId" select="generate-id()"/>
            <xsl:if test="parent::tei:w or @rend='trennstrich'">
                <span class="reg">-</span>
                <xsl:if test="@rend='trennstrich'">
                    <span class="orig">-</span>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
<!-- here I tried adding the <xsl:if> -->
        <xsl:choose><!-- ancestor:tei:cell hinzugefügt wegen Tabelle, SK 07.06.2019 -->
            <xsl:when test="generate-id((ancestor::tei:p[not(descendant::tei:cell)] | ancestor::tei:cell | ancestor::tei:head)//tei:lb[1]) != $myId">
                <br/>
            </xsl:when>  ->
            
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::tei:p/@resp">
                <br/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
           <!-- <br/>-->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        
    </xsl:template>
```

I am at the moment unable to integrate what I want to this transformation, thus I have returned once more to the mighty stackoverflow!

If I only run one transformation it works.
namely this one:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:lb[position() mod 5 = 0]">
    <span class="linenumber">
        <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </span>
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I integrate this in our template froma bove so that it's working? :-D

I tried unsuccessfully to integrate the `<xsl:template>` with

```
 <xsl:if test="tei:lb[tei:lb[position() mod 5 = 0]">
<span class="linenumber"><xsl:number level="any"/></span>
</xsl:if>
```

in the aforementioned XSL, I added a comment at the position!
Can anyone help me?
All the best,
K

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: v1.0 for all :-) Will add above as well

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 I believe your best option is to add an `xsl:if` instruction to your existing template matching `tei:lb` and place the numbering there.

Comment: I just tried that :-/ to no avail ... 
tried with ```<xsl:if>``` won't display the span with the line number

Comment: It's difficult to advise without a [mcve]. The position of each `tei:lb` depends on how you applied templates to it. If you use the default model, then the positions in the supplied example will be 1, 10, 18, 31, 44... because there are other siblings.

Comment: BTW, it does display the number when position is 10.

Comment: I fear a minimal reproducible example is hard to get by, the XSLT-script is 3000 lines of code and the TEI-file ~20000. The posted TEI-xml contains all the cases and the tei:lb-template I posted above contains all the rules that deal with the tei:lb ... I dunno whether I can compose a better example :-( 

I know that my template without the other rules works but not when I integrate it into the huge file ... :-D

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have two conflicting statements. You say your standalone template works, but adding an `xsl:if` using the same test to the existing template does not. The only way this can be true is that the two templates are not applied in the same way - but we do not see this part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238167/discussion-between-kwunsch-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: So you think I somewhere have another tei:lb template, that I'm missing somewhere :-D

Comment: No, I am saying I don't know how you apply these templates, therefore I am not able to help.